# How to reset the oninput() html event after first use?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a db search form with multiple fields. Two of them, `job_id` and `job_desc`, I want to be disabled when the other one is used and vice versa. I have written a small `Javascript` function to do this.

Here is my form code:

```
<input type="text" id="job_id" oninput="input('job_id','job_desc')" onblur="blur('job_id','job_desc')">
<textarea id="job_desc" oninput="input('job_desc','job_id')" onblur="blur('job_desc','job_id')"></textarea>
```

Here is my `Javascript` code:

```
function input(a,b)
    {
    var a = document.getElementById(a);
    var b = document.getElementById(b);
    alert("This will disable "+b); // Let the user know we are disabling the other field
    b.value = ""; // Empty the other field
    b.disabled = true; // Disable the other field
    }

function blur(a,b)
    {
    var a = document.getElementById(a);
    var b = document.getElementById(b);
    if(a.value = "") // If the field is empty...
        {
        b.disabled = false; // Enable the other field.
        }
    }
```

I have these problems:

1) For some reason my second field does not re-enable once the first field is empty and blurred. This leads me to believe the `onblur()` event is not working.

2) Once I type in some text, I get the alert once and it's all good. However, when I empty the field and the re-input some text, the alert doesn't trigger a second time. How do I reset the `oninput()` event?

Here is my fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q11m3ahz/)

Comment: Just FYI, it doesn't work in the fiddle because you should change the settings to "No wrap - in <head>" (now you get `ReferenceError: input is not defined` because the script is executed onload).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "**onkeyup**" event instead of the other events:

**The HTML Code would be :**

```
<input id="job_id" onkeyup="input('job_id','job_desc')">
<br>
<textarea id="job_desc" onkeyup="input('job_desc','job_id')"></textarea>
```

**And the JS funciton :**

```
function input(a, b) {
        var ea = document.getElementById(a); // We put A in a variable
        var eb = document.getElementById(b); // We put B in a variable
        if(ea.value != ""){ // If the element have a value / text in it
            if(!eb.disabled) // we check if the other element is disabled, if not, we trigger the alert
                alert("This will disable " + b); // Let the user know we are disabling the other field

            eb.value = ""; // Empty the other field
            eb.disabled = true; // Disable the other field   
        }else{ // if the element's value is empty (which means that we have erased the existing value)
            alert(b + " is now enabled"); // Let the user know we are enabling the other field
            eb.disabled = false; // We re-enable the field
        }
    }
```

It will work fine on all the browsers..
I hope it will help you !

Comment: How can we make it so the alert doesn't trigger with every character entered?

Comment: This is not exactly what I had in mind, but it works great and that's what really matters. Last thing, could you please add in some comments so I understand how the problem was solved?

Comment: Also, are the {} missing after the `if(!eb.disabled)` on purpose?

Comment: The comments are added. for the {}, when you have an IF statement and you only need to write one command after if, you can simply bypass the {} tags. if(!eb.disabled) alert("This will disable " + b); **AND** if(!eb.disabled){ alert("This will disable " + b);} **will give the same result**

Answer (score 1):

Besides the solution provided, the reason your code did not work is it was conflicting with a [native `blur()` function on the window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.blur), and so your `blur` call was calling that instead of your own `blur` function. You need to change its name.

Another issue once you fix that is in

```
if(a.value = "") // If the field is empty...
```

it should have two `=` signs for comparison.

```
if(a.value == "") // If the field is empty...
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/q11m3ahz/6/